# Regular expression to accept 5 characters with optional

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, regex, asp.net-mvc

Hi i have to write a regular expression that should match the format like `A12BC`. Here first 2 characters that is `A` & `1` is mandatory and next 3 characters `2`, `B` & `C` are optional. Currently my regEx works if i give the string value as `A12BC`.

When I give the input as `A1B` it should not match but my regular expression matches and gives me the result as susses. Can any one please help me and modify my RegExp so 
that it behaves as per below:

- Case "A1" : Should match
- Case "A1B" : Should not match (this case is not working)
- Case "A12B" : Should match
- Case "A12BC" : Should match
- Case "A12BCD" : Should not match

My regular expression is as below:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]?[a-zA-Z]?[a-zA-Z]?$
```

Comment: what language are you using? `C#` or `tsql`? remove necessary tags from the question.

Comment: @Typist I am using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure that the third character, if present, is a digit, make third character mandatory in an optional group, like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9]([0-9][a-zA-Z]?[a-zA-Z]?)?$
```

This expression says that if the third character is present, it needs to match a digit. The two trailing letters are optional, too.

Note: you can simplify your expression by using predefined [*Character Classes*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#character_classes) `\w` for letters and `\d` for digits. Remember that you need to double backslashes for use in "plain" string literals (as opposed to verbatim string literals, in which backslashes are not doubled).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9](?:[0-9][a-zA-Z]{0,2})?$
```

In the `2BC` pattern, you have to make the digit mandatory before allowing zero, one or two letters.

`(?:[0-9][a-zA-Z]{0,2})?` matches an empty string, or a digit, or a digit followed by a letter, or a digit followed by two letters, but *not* a single letter.

`(?:...)` is a non capturing group, see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/eP2iY9).

Comment: U r solution also works but how is different form dasblinkenlight they both looks one and the same in functionality

Comment: @SanjuRao: The differences are insignificant here, they are basically the same written in a slightly different style.